# Help Identifying This Spigot: 1/2" x R?

Tags: plumbing, identify-a-tool

I'm trying to figure out what the threading on this spigot is. It's a bit smaller then a normal hose (which slips off). I suspect it's a vacuum break, but I can't figure out the brand. [image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like standard hose thread.  There doesn't appear to be an vacuum breaker on the bib..  Where in the world are you?   perhaps this is something odd, but it does carry a "1/2" " mark that would indicate standard rather than metric sizing.

Comment: I’m in the US, I thought it might be just the bib part of the vacuum break, with the break itself removed?

Comment: I suspect your hose is the problem, not the hose bib.

Comment: If garden hose thread doesn't fit, have you tested 3/4" pipe thread? The male thread of both should be the same OD (1.05") with different thread pitch (11.5 TPI for the garden hose; 14 for the pipe thread). I guess if the garden hose slips off then a pipe thread fitting should too.. :-(